# Quicksort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, quick-sort

Here is the implementation I ended up with. Please post your feedback!

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>

inline void swap(int * const a, const int i, const int j) {

    const int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}

void printArray(int *a, int len) {
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf("%i ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void qsort(int * const a, const int len) {

    if(len < 2)
        return;

    const int pivot = a[rand() % len];

    printf("Choosed pivot %i\n", pivot);

    int lower = 0;
    int upper = len - 1;

    while(true) {

        while(a[lower] < pivot)
            lower++;

        while(a[upper] > pivot)
            upper--;

        printArray(a, len);

        if(lower == upper)
            break;

        swap(a, lower, upper);
    }

    printf("First Part ");
    printArray(a, lower);
    printf("Second Part ");
    printArray(a + lower + 1, len - lower - 1);
    printf("\n");

    qsort(a, lower);
    qsort(a + lower + 1, len - lower - 1);
}

int main() {

    int a[] = {1, 7, 3, 6, 5, 9, 2, 0, 4, 8};
    int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

    qsort(a, len);
    printArray(a, len);

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: It may be tagged C++ but this looks more like C code. You need to learn to utilize the standard library more.

Comment: That improved code may be put into a self-answer instead, if further review is not needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>
```

If you're writing C++ prefer `cout` and `cin` provided by iostream. They provide much better type-safety compared to their C counterparts. OTOH, you can still use `printf` and `scanf` if you don't need the extra flexibility provided by C++ streams and you want to keep overhead to a minimal. At any rate, it doesn't make sense to include both headers here -- you're either using one or the other.

---

```
inline void swap(int *const a, const int i, const int j) 
// ...
```

You don't need to write your own swap. The standard library provides a fully working `std::swap` which you can call like this:

```
std::swap(a[lower], a[upper]);
```

---

Note that const isn't really adding anything here for your qsort prototype since everything's pass-by-value. A subtle point is that pointer `*a` below is *also* pass-by-value. Changing `*a` in qsort won't affect where the original 'a' pointers to(the one passed by main).

```
void qsort(int * const a, const int len)
// ...
```

This qsort signature is more reminiscence of a C-style function than C++. In C++ it's more common to accept a range to sort by templatizing the parameters with iterator types. Something more akin to this for example:

```
template <class RANDOMIT>
void qsort(RANDOMIT begin, const RANDOMIT &end);
```

This is well covered in other quicksort questions already. Take a look [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1259/71) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6257/71) for a more detailed explanation and other ideas you can explore.

---

I would also factor out the partitioning code to its own function just to keep the tasks well-defined.

```
while(true) {
    while(a[lower] < pivot)
        lower++;
    while(a[upper] > pivot)
        upper--;

    printArray(a, len);

    if(lower == upper)
        break;

    swap(a, lower, upper);
}
```

There's also a bug lurking above -- duplicate items will cause an infinite loop. A possible fix might be:

```
while(true) 
{
    // ...
    if(lower >= upper) break;

    if(a[lower] != a[upper]) { std::swap(a[lower], a[upper]); }
    ++lower, --upper;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the review! I know about iostream, however I hate the additional typing required to use it.

Comment: `std::swap` should rather be used as `using std::swap; swap(x, y);` - This will allow argument-dependent lookup to use user-defined overloads of `swap` in other namespaces.

Comment: Is there any reason why you did not suggest using [std::partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)?

Comment: I did not know about std::partition, I really have to look into this.

Comment: I'm not seeing the bug in that code you say has one - care to point out what it is?

Comment: @Ryan What happens when `a[lower] == a[upper] == pivot` assuming `upper` and `lower` hasn't crossed yet?

Comment: @greatwolf Ok yes I see it. Subtle error, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I understand that passing the length around can be useful if you pass dynamic arrays to your functions, but you could still write some reusable helper functions to handle statically-sized arrays:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t size(const T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

With this function, you can write:

```
int a[] = {1, 7, 3, 6, 5, 9, 2, 0, 4, 8};
int len = size(a);
```

---

You are using `std::rand`, but you don't seed it with [`std::srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) first. Anyway, if you have a C++11 compiler, try to use [the new `<random>` module](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead. Standard methods that may use `std::rand`, such as [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) are even deprecated in C++14.

Answer (score 6):

@Victor: Cover all the points I wanted:

So just one very minor not pick.

```
int a[] = {1, 7, 3, 6, 5, 9, 2, 0, 4, 8};
int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
```

Prefer to define this in terms of the actual elements. Then if you change the type of the array you only need to change in one place:

```
int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); // a[0] will always have the correct type even if you
                                  // change the underlying type of the array. And since
                                  // is evaluated at compile time will always work.
```

Comment 1:

```
while(a[lower] < pivot)
    lower++;
while(a[upper] > pivot)
    upper--;
```

Which set do elements that are equal to the pivot go into?

Comment 2:

```
    if(lower == upper)
        break;
```

How often will that happen?

Answer (score 0):

With C++11 and std::partition the code is waaay smaller and easier to read, I ended up with:

```
template <typename it_t>
void qsort(it_t begin, it_t end)
{
    typedef decltype(*begin) elem_t;

    size_t length = end - begin;

    if (length < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    elem_t pivot = *(begin + ( rand() % length));

    it_t newPivotPos = partition(begin, end, [=] (elem_t elem) { return elem < pivot; });

    qsort(begin, newPivotPos);
    qsort(newPivotPos, end);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `decltype(*begin)` to return the underlying type.  `decltype(*begin)` doesn't behave the same as `std::iterator_traits<it_t>::value_type` (see a [proxy class example](http://ideone.com/92jZXY) of `std::vector<bool>`).  Use `std::distance` to calculate the elements between iterators (still constant time for your random access iterators, linear time for others).  If you are suggesting c++11, don't use `rand()`. Instead, write a [random selector](https://gist.github.com/cbsmith/5538174) with the `<random>` library.  Use PascalCase for user-defined class/type names (`Iter_t`, `Elem_t`).

Comment: Thx for the comment! But the link to the proxy class example is broken.

Comment: However I do not understand why I should use distance instead of just minus is there any case where minus would not work?

Comment: @Nils [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) is usable on `InputIterator` whereas `operator -` is only required for `RandomAccessIterator`. In short `std::distance` allows template code to function for a broader range of iterator types.